# Cannot print the sum of all the numbers present in the txt file

Tags: java, sum

I have some numbers in a file but I don't know how to calculate the sum of all the numbers in the txt file.

```
class sum {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Spencer Du\\eclipse-workspace\\Exam prep\\src\\examPaper20162017\\sum.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            int num;
            int sum = 0;

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    num = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
                else scan.next();
            }

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    sum+= scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(sum);
                }
                else scan.next();
            }
            System.out.println(sum);        
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) { // may be throw by new FileReader(...)
            System.out.println( e );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {  // may be thrown by readLine()
            System.out.println( e );
        }       
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
1
6
3
9
12
0
```

I can get all the integers from txt file printed on a separate line but for the last digit it should be the sum. It does not calculate the sum but gives me a zero. How can I fix this so the sum of the first five digits prints me a summed value and not zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use two while loops. The first while loop completely reads the entire file, leaving the second while loop with no more input to parse (and thus no numbers to sum). Combine the two loops into one like this:

```
       while (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                num = scan.nextInt();
                sum+= num;
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            else scan.next();
        }
```

Two separate while loops could work in theory if you create a new scanner instance before using the second loop. Then the second loop will use a "fresh" scanner and get all the input numbers again.